# How can I make dynamic tables with Datatables?

Tags: dynamic, datatables

I'm trying to find a way to create dynamic tables for reports with Datatables but I dont seem to find a good way. Does anybody know how can I do it or is there any app or tool that can help me? Something similar to Reportico. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bear in mind that questions asking for recommendations for libraries, tools, etc. are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at Stack Overflow (see item #3 in the numbered list): "_they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: Apart from that, what have you researched, so far? What exactly are you looking to do where you need specific help to solve a specific problem? There are various Stack Overflow questions about creating [dynamic DataTables](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+dynamic+site%3Astackoverflow.com). There are also similar questions on the [DataTables forum](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+dynamic+site%253Adatatables.net).